# If I import Firebase, does that also include FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Just wondering if "import Firebase" includes everything, or if FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase should be imported in addition.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By importing Firebase, you just import `FirebaseApp`. While this is a core part of Firebase, you'll need to import the additional modules that you actually use.